# Slick - one to many table schema

Tags: scala, slick

Suppose I have case classes as follows:

```
case class Warehouse(name:String, products:Seq[Product])
case class Product(name:String)
```

I would like to define a table which is bound to the `Warehouse` type

```
class Warehouses(tag: Tag) extends Table[Warehouse](tag, "warehouses") {
      def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
      def name = column[String]("name")
      def products = ???
}
```

I could define my table with tuples and reference `Warehouses` from `Products` - that would be one-to-many relationship I need. However I need my Tables to reflect my domain classes so I can execute DBIO actions and get `Warehouse` not a tuple:

```
val warehouses = TableQuery[Warehouses]
db.run(warehouses.filter(_.id === 2).result.head) //this is of type Warehouse
```

How can I define a schema from the case class which contains a collection?

Comment: From DB design point of view, you need an ID for products plus a separate table which describes many-to-many relationship between Products and Warehouses. Every entry in that table would be (Product_ID, Warehouse_ID). If you are certain that one product always belongs to a particular warehouse, then you can add warehouse_id to products table as a foreign key. My personal preference is a separate table with ID pairs.

Comment: Please go through slick documentation for more idea on Slick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Slick is not ORM

So, Slick does not support nested objects like hibernate. If you strongly want to have nested objects model Slick is not a suitable solution for your use case. This point is explicitly mentioned in the slick documentation as well.

Your use case in Slick is modelled like this

```
case class WarehouseModel(name:String, id: Long)
case class ProductModel(name:String, productId: Long)
case class WarehouseProductsModel(warehouseId: Long, productId: Long)
```

`WarehouseProductsModel` captures the `one-many` relationship between Product and Warehouse

*Note that above design looks like the typical database design one would choose to do in case of one-many relationship. In Slick these models represents relational tables. So, for each table we need to have one model which represents that table in code. Slick helps in writing sql agnostic, composable, reusable, typesafe and scala collection like queries. So end of the day Slick code looks like Scala collections manipulation code.*

Comment: Go through this video for more info on Slick https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciyjJLYIySY

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!